# Flask-Admin: add a search box component under the column header to filter column items

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-admin

In the context of Flask-Admin, I'm trying to find a way to implement a search box to filter column items under the column title header.

I came across a similar question on Stackoverflow which discussed an implementation close to what I want to do (Cf. [column_filter by grandparent's property in flask-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47931287/column-filter-by-grandparents-property-in-flask-admin)).

I added a custom filter using the following code:

```py
class FilterColumn(BaseSQLAFilter):
    def __init__(self, column, label=None, options=None, name=None, col=None):
        super(FilterColumn, self).__init__(column, label, options, name)
        self.column = column
        self.col = col

    def apply(self, query, value, alias=None):
        return query.filter(self.column == value)

    def operation(self):
        return u'equals'

    def get_options(self, view):
        model_class = self.column.class_
        column = getattr(model_class, self.col, None)

        if column:
            items = view.session.query(column).distinct().order_by(column)
            return [(item[0], item[0]) for item in items]

        return [item for item in session.query(Person).all()]
```

Then, in my view, I specified the column filter like this :

```py
class PersonView(ModelView):

    ...
    
    # specify column filter 
    column_filters = [FilterColumn(column=Person.pref_label, label='Personne e-NDP', col='pref_label')]
    
    ...
    
    # add to get filter options always up-to-date
    @expose('/')
    def index_view(self):
        self._refresh_filters_cache()
        return super(PersonView, self).index_view()
```

However, I only want to keep the search component under the column header, like this scheme:

[image]

If you have any tips or clues on this, or if you know of a method in flask admin (I can't find it in the doc except 'column_filters'), thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The **FilterColumn** class is a subclass of **BaseSQLAFilter**, it will be displayed as a dropdown list of options in the filter bar. If you want to have a search box instead, you need to create a custom filter class that inherits from BaseFilter instead.

```
class SearchFilter(BaseFilter):
def __init__(self):
    ...


def filter_query(self, query, value):
    if value:
        return query.filter(self.column.like('%{}%'.format(value)))
    return query

def get_field_data(self, view):
    return {
        'label': self.label,
        'value': view._get_field_value(self.column),
        'placeholder': 'Search...',
    }
```

This filter class has two methods: `filter_query` and `get_field_data`. The `filter_query` method is called when the user submits the search form. It takes a query object and a search value as input, and it returns a filtered query object. The `get_field_data` method is called to get the data that will be displayed in the filter bar.

Post this, you need to add custom filter class to your models

```
column_filters = [SearchFilter(column=Person.pref_label, label='label1')]
```

Once you have done this, the search box will be displayed under the "label1" column header in the admin interface.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using column_searchable_list to add search functionality under the column header( In the PersonView class)
In this way you may  enable a search box under the pref_label column header, allowing you to search for items based on the specified columns.